# 2 class library projects with different icons, why?

Tags: c#

I have different projects in my solution, however the icons are different. do you know why?

[image: project icons]

I checked the project properties, both are saying class library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the symbol for a unit test project.

[image]

The output type for these will still show as "Class Library".

[image]